# What kinematic formula is this?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, distance

I think it's one of the kinematic equations but I don't recognize the form.

$$d = d_0 + \frac 1 2 a_{cc}t^2$$

It was given in a physics problem,where we are given points (x) and (y).
where $x = t^2$ and $y = d$. 
We insert this into a graphing calculator (linear regression). 
Which gives us a and b. a being the slope and b the y intercept.

We are then told to find the regression equation in the forum of

$$d = d_0 + \frac 1 2 a_{cc}t^2$$

Comment: Do you know the four kinematics equations?

Comment: I have them in my book and notes. I don't know them by memory. @Steeven

Comment: Have you considered looking them up in your book and notes?

Comment: @CRDrost Yes, I'm looking at them. The problem is that I can't figure out which one it is.

Comment: Would you mind adding those four kinematic equations to the question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of insufficient research effort.

Comment: This isn't a homework problem, I was just trying to get a better understanding of the problem above. Knowing what the equation is would help me understand further, instead of just plugging numbers in. I understand that some of you thought that I was trying to get a homework answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a constant acceleration $a$, then we have for the equation of motion:

$$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = a $$

Ad if we integrate this we get the velocity:

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = v = at + C $$

where $C$ is the constant of integration. If we say that $u$ is the velocity when $t=0$ the constant $C$ is just $u$, so we get one of the SUVAT equations:

$$ v = u + at \tag{1} $$

We can get the distance by integrating again to get:

$$ x = ut + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2 + C $$

where again $C$ is the constant of integration. This time we specify that the distance at time $t=0$ is $s_0$, in which case we get $C = s_0$ and we get another of the SUVAT equations (using the symbol $s$ for $x$):

$$ s = s_0 + ut + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2 \tag{2} $$

And this last equation is the one your physics problem uses, with the initial velocity $u$ set to zero. That is, if the object starts from rest, $u=0$, at a distance $s_0 = d_0$ equation (2) becomes:

$$ s = d_0 + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2 \tag{2} $$

which is your equation.